# How do I create a regression model with multiple outputs in tf.keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm attempting to train a regression model to predict attributes of music such as BPM. The model takes in spectrograms of audio snippets that are 256x128px png files and outputs a couple continuous values. I have the following code so far that I have developed based upon [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/load_data/images) on the tensorflow website:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import random
import pathlib

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
TRAINING_DATA_DIR = r'specgrams'

def gen_model():
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(256, 128, 3)),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001),
                  loss='mse',
                  metrics=['mse', 'mae'])

    return model


def fetch_batch(batch_size=1000):
    all_image_paths = []
    all_image_labels = []

    data_root = pathlib.Path(TRAINING_DATA_DIR)
    files = data_root.iterdir()

    for file in files:
        file = str(file)
        all_image_paths.append(os.path.abspath(file))
        label = file[:-4].split('-')[2:]
        label = float(label[0]) / 200, int(label[1]) / 1000.0
        all_image_labels.append(label)

    def preprocess_image(path):
        img_raw = tf.io.read_file(path)
        image = tf.image.decode_png(img_raw, channels=3)
        image = tf.image.resize(image, [256, 128])
        image /= 255.0
        return image

    def preprocess(path, label):
        return preprocess_image(path), label

    path_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(all_image_paths)
    image_ds = path_ds.map(preprocess_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    label_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(all_image_labels)
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((image_ds, label_ds))
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(os.listdir(TRAINING_DATA_DIR)))
    ds = ds.repeat()
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
    ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

    return ds

ds = fetch_batch()
model = gen_model()
model.fit(ds, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=10)
```

However I believe I have made a mistake with the structure of my model or how I am preprocessing the training data because I get an error about incorrect dimensions but I'm struggling to narrow down exactly where the issue is. I understand that the guide I followed was for  classification problem as opposed to regression and my "labels" are an array of 2 value which is what is causing the problem but I'm not sure how to resolve this.

For context the filenames are in the format `xxx-xxx-A-B.png` where A and B are the two desired output values of the model. A is a floating-point value somewhere between 70 and 180 and B is an integer value between 0-1000. As such the `label` variable for each image looks something like this: `(0.64, 0.319)`.

This is the error I am seeing when I attempt to execute the above script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cainy\Desktop\BeatNet\training.py", line 60, in <module>
    model.fit(ds, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=3)
  File "C:\Users\cainy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 791, in fit
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "C:\Users\cainy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1515, in fit_generator
    steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
  File "C:\Users\cainy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 257, in model_iteration
    batch_outs = batch_function(*batch_data)
  File "C:\Users\cainy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1259, in train_on_batch
    outputs = self._fit_function(ins)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
  File "C:\Users\cainy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 3217, in __call__
    outputs = self._graph_fn(*converted_inputs)
  File "C:\Users\cainy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 558, in __call__
    return self._call_flat(args)
  File "C:\Users\cainy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 627, in _call_flat
    outputs = self._inference_function.call(ctx, args)
  File "C:\Users\cainy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 415, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "C:\Users\cainy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 66, in quick_execute
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 2
     [[{{node metrics/accuracy/Squeeze}}]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_734]
```

Edit: I have uploaded the source code to GitHub [here](https://github.com/cainy393/BeatNet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You currently only have 1 output - a tensor with length 2 (per batch element). If you want to use/monitor separate losses you'll need to [unstack](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unstack) it in both the model output and the labels.

I'm not sure if `models.Sequential` will be suitable, but you can definitely use the functional API:

```py
def gen_model():
    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(256, 128, 3), dtype=tf.float32)
    x = inputs
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
    a, b = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(tf.unstack, arguments=dict(axis=-1))(x)
    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[a, b])
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001),
                  loss=['mse', 'mae'],
                  metrics=[['mse'], ['mae']])
    return model
```

And in your preprocessing:

```py
def preprocess(path, label):
    return preprocess_image(path), tf.unstack(label, axis=-1)
```

Comment: Yeah I have another question up regarding that. I have realised my loss metric should something like mse instead. However, I'm not able to run this model at all because I don't know how to output 2 values without having 2 separate models for each value.

Comment: answer updated. Can't test it without your data, so post any errors here :)

Comment: Ah thank you! That is looking promising, I will investigate. I'm worried about copyright issues with distributing music but I can upload some sample spectrograms that I have generated. [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DcwYjB1iUzZmym0P5btkcb5kpR5QpgGU) is a zip file with a thousand images :)