# How do I structure a Keras model for a custom image regression problem?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm attempting to develop a regression model using Tensorflow 2 and the keras API using a custom data set of png images. However, I'm not entirely sure what layers I should be using and how. I put together what I thought was a very simple model as a starting point however when I attempt to train the model the loss and accuracy values printed out are consistently 0. This leads me to believe my loss calculations are not working but I have no idea why. Below is a snippet of my source code, the full project for which can be found [here](https://github.com/cainy393/BeatNet/blob/master/training_bpm_only.py):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import random
import pathlib

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
TRAINING_DATA_DIR = r'specgrams'

def gen_model():
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(256, 128, 3)),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model


def fetch_batch(batch_size=1000):
    all_image_paths = []
    all_image_labels = []

    data_root = pathlib.Path(TRAINING_DATA_DIR)
    files = data_root.iterdir()

    for file in files:
        file = str(file)
        all_image_paths.append(os.path.abspath(file))
        label = file[:-4].split('-')[2:3]
        label = float(label[0]) / 200
        all_image_labels.append(label)

    def preprocess_image(path):
        img_raw = tf.io.read_file(path)
        image = tf.image.decode_png(img_raw, channels=3)
        image = tf.image.resize(image, [256, 128])
        image /= 255.0
        return image

    def preprocess(path, label):
        return preprocess_image(path), label

    path_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(all_image_paths)
    image_ds = path_ds.map(preprocess_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    label_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(all_image_labels)
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((image_ds, label_ds))
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(os.listdir(TRAINING_DATA_DIR)))
    ds = ds.repeat()
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
    ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

    return ds

ds = fetch_batch()
model = gen_model()
model.fit(ds, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=10)
```

The code above is supposed to read in some spectrograms stored as 256 x 128 px png files, convert them to tensors and fit them so a regression model to predict a value (in this case the BPM of the music used to generate the spectrogram). The image file names contain the BPM which is divided by 200 to produce a value between 0 and 1 as the label.

As stated before, this code does run successfully but after each training step the loss and accuracy values printed out are always exactly 0.00000 and do not change.

It's also worth noting that I actually want my model to predict multiple values, not just a single BPM value but this is a separate issue and as such I have posted a separate question for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55884849/how-do-i-create-a-regression-model-with-multiple-outputs-in-tf-keras).

Comment: Yes. You need another loss function for the regression like `mean_squared_error`.  I think i can give better answer if you let me know what is the label.  I want to make sure whether your problem needs `regression model` or not.

Comment: @yaho cho I'm attempting to predict the tempo of a piece of music, as I said at the bottom I'm actually attempting to label each item with a couple of values but tried to simplify this to a single value as part of my debugging process.

Ideally I want to predict a BPM (beats per minute) value, typically in the range 70-180 and accurate to 2 decimal places, and an Inizio value (a number of ms till the first beat, typically an integer between 0 and 1000).

Comment: I see. Anyway, try `mean_squared_error` for regression. But, I think accuracy might be low because It's difficult to find any linear rules from image. I am not sure before I execute it in myself.

Comment: If I get this problem, I will try to use histogram instead of real image.  Or, I will try to make classification model with y label which are classified by range of tempo. it is just my hypothesis.  Please try many kind of ways.

Comment: @yahocho Thank you for you advice. Using MSE I did start to see loss values that were declining! However as you suspected, there were issues with the accuracy and I never saw it rise from 0. Exactly how to process the inputs and what model layers to use is the subject of my dissertation on this project. Any ideas you have on avenues to improve this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192504/discussion-between-yaho-cho-and-cainy393).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyway for the answer. Regression model requires loss function related such as 'mean_squared_error', 'mean_absolut_error', 'mean_absolute_percentage_error' and 'mean_squared_logarithmic_error.

```
def gen_model():
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(256, 128, 3)),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),        
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                  loss='mean_squared_error',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

Comment: Thank you! My main issue was using the wrong loss metric, now that I'm using mse I am having much more success.